# Play audio from video in background

Tags: android, audio, video, android-videoview

i have a problem with videoview android. Now, i play video stream in videoview and when minimized video automatically paused. The next step i wanna videoview not paused when minimized.

can anyone help?
really appreciate. thx

Answer (score 0):

you can use windowManager and put your videoView on window manager when your activity is onPause state.check this link.
http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/

and if you dont want to see video just set the visibility to invisible so you can paly only audio without seeing video.

Comment: hmm... what i want is video keep stream when home button pressed, so when i back to application, video is not re load, but keep continue. any idea?